# Dagger 2 cannot be provided without an constructor

Tags: java, android, dagger-2

Sorry for my english, now i begin learn dagger2 and i cant understand why i have error:

> Error:(9, 10) error:
>   test.dagger.dagger.modules.MainActivityPresenterModule cannot be
>   provided without an @Inject constructor or from an @Provides- or
>   @Produces-annotated method.
>   test.dagger.dagger.modules.MainActivityPresenterModule is injected at
>   test.dagger.view.activitys.MainActivity.mainActivityPresenterModule
>   test.dagger.view.activitys.MainActivity is injected at
>   test.dagger.dagger.components.AppComponent.injectMainActivity(mainActivity)

**App**

```
public class App extends Application {

    private static AppComponent component;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        component = DaggerAppComponent.create();
    }

    public static AppComponent getComponent() {
        return component;
    }

}
```

**AppComponent**

```
@Component(modules = {MainActivityPresenterModule.class})
public interface AppComponent {
    void injectMainActivity(MainActivity mainActivity);
}
```

**MainActivityPresenterModule**

```
@Module
public class MainActivityPresenterModule {

    @Provides
    MainActivityPresenter provideActivityPresenter(NetworkUtils networkUtils) {
        return new MainActivityPresenter(networkUtils);
    }

    @Provides
    NetworkUtils provideNetworkUtils(){
        return new NetworkUtils();
    }


}
```

**NetworkUtils**

```
public class NetworkUtils {

    public boolean isConnection() {
        return true;
    }

}
```

**MainActivityPresenter**

```
public class MainActivityPresenter {

    NetworkUtils networkUtils;

    public MainActivityPresenter(NetworkUtils networkUtils) {
        this.networkUtils = networkUtils;
    }

    public void getUser(){
        if(networkUtils.isConnection()) {
            Log.e("getUser", "getUser");
        } else {
            Log.e("no internet", "no internet connection");
        }
    }

}
```

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Inject
    MainActivityPresenterModule mainActivityPresenterModule;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        App.getComponent().injectMainActivity(MainActivity.this);


    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can inject only the things that are provided in the classes annotated with `@Module` (only methods inside that module which are annotated with `@Provides`). So, you can do `@Inject MainActivityPresenter presenter`, for instance, not try to inject the whole module, like you tried to do. Modules should be registered on Dagger initialisation, like this (in App#onCreate)

```
component = DaggerAppComponent.builder()
    .mainActivityPresenterModule(MainActivityPresenterModule())
    .build()
```

In MainActivity you only need to call inject to be able to inject your `@Inject MainActivityPresenter presenter` or any other injects defined in the module, like so:

```
@Inject MainActivityPresenter presenter    

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
   (application as App).component.inject(this)

   // after #inject(this) above you can start using your injections:

   presenter.getUser()
}
```

Sorry, I wrote code snippets in Kotlin as it was much less to write that way, hopefully you get the idea how it looks in Java.